# What is the distribution of $Y = X^2$ given $X$ is Student's $t$ with $k$ df?

Tags: probability-distributions

Given a random variable $X$ being a Student's $t$ with $k$ degrees of freedom, find the distribution of $Y = X^2$.

$$f_X(x;k) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{k\pi} \ \Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k}\right)}^{-\frac{k+1}{2}}$$

Since the Student's $t$ doesn't have a MGF and its CF is so ugly it gives me chills I don't know what to do.

Comment: Anyway, can you try working out a general expression for $P[Y\leq y]$ using either the CDF or PDF for $X$?

Comment: @Michael very funny. Student's $t$ is a well known probability distribution, and I even provided its density. CF = characteristical function, $E[e^{itX}]$.

Comment: I have never heard of a probability distibution called "student's t."  Anway, can you specify the interval of $x$ values over which your density is defined, and also, try answering my second comment?

Comment: [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)

Comment: And I will try that, let me get back to you in a jiff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45902/discussion-between-michael-and-gabriel-vivaldini).

Comment: Hint: $F$-distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine just showed me how to do it:

Consider $U \sim N(0,1)$ (standard normal) and $V \sim \chi^2_k$ (chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom). The Student's $t$-distribution witg $k$ degrees of freedom is computed by $$X = \frac{U}{\sqrt{\frac{V}{k}}}$$ and $Y = X^2$ is computed by $$Y = X^2 = \frac{U^2}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{V}{k}}\right)^2} = \frac{[N(0,1)]^2}{\frac{\chi^2_k}{k}} = \frac{\chi^2_1 / 1}{\chi^2_k / k} \sim F_{(1,k)}$$
where $F_{(1,k)}$ is the Fisher-Snedecor F Distribution with $(1,k)$ degrees of freedom.