# Transform Student's T distribution to Beta distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, sampling, beta-function

I want to calculate the inverse CDF of the Student's T distribution, but I only have an accurate routine for the Beta distribution available. I have tried to make a transformation, but I'm getting the wrong answers out. Could somebody check my reasoning?

Let $T$ have a Student's $T$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. Given a probability $p$, we want to find $t$ such that

$$
P(T < t) = p
$$

Let us suppose without loss of generality that $t \geq 0$, i.e. $p \geq 1/2$, since otherwise we can use symmetry to frame the problem this way. First, we transform to a $F_{1,n}$ distribution:

$$
P(T < t) = 1 - P(T > t) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} P(|T| > t) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + P(|T| < t) \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + P(T^2 < t^2) \right)
$$

Noting that $T^2$ is distributed as $F_{1,n}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941634/what-is-the-distribution-of-y-x2-given-x-is-students-t-with-k-df)), we can rearrange to get:

$$
P(F_{1,n} < t^2) = 2p - 1
$$

Next we use the fact that if $B$ has a $Beta(\frac{\alpha_1}{2}, \frac{\alpha_2}{2})$ distribution, then $\frac{\alpha_2 B}{\alpha_1 (1 - B)}$ has an $F_{\alpha_1, \alpha_2}$ distribution (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713626/beta-distribution-to-f-distribution)), to transform our expression (with $\alpha_1 = 1, \alpha_2 = n$):

$$
P \left( \frac{nB}{1 - B} < t^2 \right) = 2p - 1 
$$

We use $B > 0$ to rearrange the inequality:

$$
P \left( B < \frac{t^2}{n + t^2} \right) = 2p-1
$$

Letting $F_B$ be the CDF of $B$, we set $x = F_B^{-1}(2p - 1) = \frac{t^2}{n + t^2}$ and we can solve the original problem for t:

$$
t = \sqrt{ \frac{xn}{1 - x} }
$$

Where the positive square root is taken because of our assumption that $t > 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Presumably you want $T$ to have a Student's $t$ distribution with $n$ (rather than $t$) degrees of freedom.  Your claim is that $F_{t_n}^{-1}(p) =  \sqrt{ n\dfrac{F_{Beta(1/2, n/2)}^{-1}(2p-1)}{1 - F_{Beta(1/2, n/2)}^{-1}(2p-1)} }$ at least when $\frac12 \le p \lt 1$.  Then  similarly $F_{t_n}^{-1}(p) =  -\sqrt{ n\dfrac{F_{Beta(1/2, n/2)}^{-1}(1-2p)}{1 - F_{Beta(1/2, n/2)}^{-1}(1-2p)} }$  when $0 \lt p \le \frac12$. That seems to be correct, for the reasons you give.   Though note that calculating the Beta distribution quantile function is not simple.

Comment: Thanks @Henry . Yes I did mean $n$ df, I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your approach is generally correct if you want to generate realizations of a Student's $t$-distributed random variable $T$ from a suitable Beta-distributed random variable $X$.  You would presumably use a third, auxiliary random variable, say $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2)$; e.g.,

$$X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(1/2, n/2), \quad Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2), \\ T = (2Y-1) \sqrt{\frac{nX}{1-X}} \sim \operatorname{StudentT}(n).$$

The reason for the additional Bernoulli variable is so that you can generate negative realizations of $T$, not just the positive ones.

While your derivation employs the "inverse CDF" method, this doesn't actually yield a closed-form inverse CDF for the Student's $t$ distribution, since there isn't a simple closed form for the inverse of the beta CDF.  It only shows how, if you have access to a random number generator that can generate realizations from a beta distribution, you can use it to get Student's $t$ realizations via a simple transformation.

Comment: Thanks. I won't be generating realisations of the random variable - the context is that I'm using the NAG library, and the Student's T inverse CDF is only accurate to about 1e-5, but their Beta routine allows greater precision. Under the hood their [Beta implementation](https://www.nag.com/numeric/nl/nagdoc_27.3/clhtml/g01/g01fec.html) uses a modified version of Newton-Raphson

Comment: You only need your $Y$ if you want random $t_n$-distributed numbers and have a generator for $\operatorname{Beta}(1/2, n/2)$ distributed numbers (perhaps found with rejection sampling as with `rbeta()` in R).  But I read the question as looking for the inverse CDF, so the equivalent of basing `qt()` on `qbeta()` in which case you do not need your $Y$